# How to pass a localstorage value as an argument in axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React app and I use Express to handle my db queries.

What I want is to pass my user id stored in localstorage into a post request.

(My app is basically a game where users can gain cards to fight against other players, and to do so, I need to update my db when a user receives a card, which is why I'm trying to do the following).
Here's my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Axios from "axios";
import axios from "axios";

const Cards = () => {

const [card, setCard] = useState([]);
const id = localStorage.getItem("id");
console.log(id) // Output is 1 (correct)

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        try {
            // Below, id should refer to localStorage.getItem("id")
            const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/getRandomCard', {id}) 
            setCard(res.data)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error:', err)
        }
    }

    fetchData()
}, []);

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            {card.map(aCard => <div className={"text-center"} key={aCard.name}> {aCard.name}
                <img alt={"Image de " + aCard.name} className={'activator'} src={'http://localhost/lfl/inc/img/players-ico/' + aCard.name} style={{width: '100%'}}/>
            </div>)}
        </div>

    </div>);
};

export default Cards;
```

And on my app.js:

```
app.post('/getRandomCard', async function (req, res) {

    const id = req.params.id;

    console.log('userid= ', id) // Output: undefined

    // ...

})
```

I'm very new to React, so I'm trying basic stuff, and maybe my code is not the better way to do what I'm actually trying to do, if so, every comment is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the post method, on the second place is object with 'body' of the request. So your data is not in the params, but its in the body.

So you have to use

```
 const id = req.body.id;
```

instead of

```
const id = req.params.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive id using params then you have to tweak your code a little bit

```
const res = await Axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/getRandomCard/${id}`)
```

And on the backend receive the code like this,

```
app.post('/getRandomCard/:id', async function (req, res) {

    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log('userid= ', id)

})
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Arek's answer works too perfectly, so what do you recommand, using body ou params for text values ?

Comment: Ik his answer is correct, you can take any route you want. I answered because if in future you end up in a situation where you send an id in the form of params, then you know how to send and receive it and mostly we send id in the form of params